# No lower right Click Hp 820

Tags: hp-touchpad

just installed xbuntu 14.04.2 lts and now my lower right click button doesn't function. the laptop has one a double set of buttons on the top and bottom of the touch pad top one work fine and the left click on the bottom works just missing the lower right.

Comment: This sounds like a Hardware issue to me

Comment: Because if the bottom left works, then it's probably not a driver issue.

Comment: I juat reinstalled windows on a spare drive to test if the buttons still functioned. In windows no issue.
In Ubuntu no lower right click.